# Rails AJAX Form Submit doesn't pass the params correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

So in my rails application I have a big form that is submitted on the Save button click but we also want to save periodically when they click on other parts on the form using ajax. So I have setup a method that submit the form as AJAX request.

```
var $frm = $(form);
$frm.unbind('submit').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: $frm.attr('method'),
    url: $frm.attr('action'),
    data: $frm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
       // Errors out in Server side and does not succeed
    }
  });
  return false;
});
$frm.submit();
```

Unfortunately this has worked in other forms but this form is a bit complex and has an array of objects passed and the following is the error I get:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: expected Hash (got String) for param `selected'
```

Does anyone know how to submit a Rails form using ajax where you pass array of items like users[] without getting this error?

Comment: What's the controller code that handles $frm.serialize()

Comment: And please post the form HTML

Answer (score 2):

Please inspect your form. This is because there is the same name, for example :

```
input type="text" name="user[email]" id="user_email"
input type="checkbox" name="user" value="1"
```

Unexpected error while processing request: expected Hash (got String) for param `selected'

text and checkbox have the same name => "user".

Answer (score 0):

this isnt an answer for this question,
but for some cases, this happen,
when you have array of data with starting index of 0: null
[ , {data:1}, {data:2}]

the leading index 0 could lead to the same error